# How to test an upgrade version of a android project?

Tags: android, google-play, android-install-apk

I have an application already in Google play and I'm developing a new version for it.

If I install mine new version with Google play version already installed it gives me `INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE`. I changed version on manifest but the error is the same.

I need to have the official version installed because the new version changes some old data and I want to test if it's ok.

How could I proceed?

Comment: Make sure the new/upgrade version has a numerically higher `versionCode` in its `manifest.xml`

Comment: I checked that already. I have version 2.04 and I'm developing version 3.0

Comment: `versioncode`, not `versionName`. `versionCode` is an integer value, so cannot be 2.04.  http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Comment: Sorry, I changed versionCode already too, from 2 to 3

Comment: What's the version code of the Google Play version? Your new version has to be higher than that. Try changing it to 300 just to test.

Comment: I tried 300 and the error is the same. Isn't anything related to the certificate I previously used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that `versionCode` is increased. It is a numerical value and each version has to have it higher than the previous one (not necessarily by 1, just higher, you can go, e.g. from 10 to 20).

`versionName` is what is displayed to the user in Google Play. It can be any value, necessarily numeric. You can even say "next version" or "the most awesome version".

```
android:versionCode="4"  <- this one needs to be increased and is numeric
android:versionName="1.0.4"  <- this is for display to the user, this is not numeric
```

Comment: So the one that you have installed is 2? Can you try to first uninstall the old version and install it back before upgrading? Maybe you already had something else installed.